# How can I upgrade my Surface Pro to Windows 8.1 without Product Key?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-surface-pro

I purchased a used MS Surface Pro on eBay.
It was delivered being factory-reset and the OS is Windows 8.0.
When I tried to upgrade it, it asked me to input Product Key which I don't have.
I did some research and factory-reset seems to make the product key lost.

How can I upgrade it to Windows 8.1?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's free in the Windows Store (i.e. no license required), you may need to make a Microsoft account to access it, however.

If you install through the Windows Store and are getting that message, you are likely not running an activated Windows 8 copy.  The key is stored in the UEFI, so try activating from My Computer > Properties.  If that fails, you may need to call.

> [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/update-from-windows-8-tutorial#update)
>   **If your PC is currently running Windows 8 or Windows RT, it's free to
>   update to Windows 8.1 or Windows RT 8.1.** And unlike previous updates
>   to Windows, you'll get this update **from the Windows Store.**